# D3 Bar Chart Zoom Not Centered

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a bar chart with zoom function. The issue is, the zooming isn't actually centered. If, I place the cursor, on a bar and zoom, the bar underneath the cursor moves away as opposed to staying there, However, if I set the `MARGIN.LEFT` = 0, then the issue is rectified and No matter what bar I have my cursor on, when I zoom the bar stays there, right underneath. Could anyone help me with this?

**Working Code Here:** https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-zoom-not-centered-sfziyk

**D3 Code:**

```
const MARGIN = {
  LEFT: 60,
  RIGHT: 40,
  TOP: 10,
  BOTTOM: 130
};
// total width incl margin
const VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 1140;
// total height incl margin
const VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 400;

const WIDTH = VIEWPORT_WIDTH - MARGIN.LEFT - MARGIN.RIGHT;
const HEIGHT = VIEWPORT_HEIGHT - MARGIN.TOP - MARGIN.BOTTOM;

const svg = d3
  .select(".chart-container")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", WIDTH + MARGIN.LEFT + MARGIN.RIGHT)
  .attr("height", HEIGHT + MARGIN.TOP + MARGIN.BOTTOM);

const g = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${MARGIN.LEFT}, ${MARGIN.TOP})`);

g.append("text")
  .attr("class", "x axis-label")
  .attr("x", WIDTH / 2)
  .attr("y", HEIGHT + 110)
  .attr("font-size", "20px")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Month");

g.append("text")
  .attr("class", "y axis-label")
  .attr("x", -(HEIGHT / 2))
  .attr("y", -60)
  .attr("font-size", "20px")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .text("");

const zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0.5, 10]).on("zoom", zoomed);
svg.call(zoom);
function zoomed(event) {
  x.range([0, WIDTH].map((d) => event.transform.applyX(d)));
  barsGroup
    .selectAll("rect.profit")
    .attr("x", (d) => x(d.month))
    .attr("width", 0.5 * x.bandwidth());
  barsGroup
    .selectAll("rect.revenue")
    .attr("x", (d) => x(d.month) + 0.5 * x.bandwidth())
    .attr("width", 0.5 * x.bandwidth());
  xAxisGroup.call(xAxisCall);
}

const x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, WIDTH]).paddingInner(0.3).paddingOuter(0.2);

const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([HEIGHT, 0]);

const xAxisGroup = g
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${HEIGHT})`);

const yAxisGroup = g.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");

const xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(x);

const yAxisCall = d3
  .axisLeft(y)
  .ticks(3)
  .tickFormat((d) => "$" + d);

const defs = svg.append("defs");
const barsClipPath = defs
  .append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "bars-clip-path")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", WIDTH)
  .attr("height", 400);

const barsGroup = g.append("g");
const zoomGroup = barsGroup.append("g");

barsGroup.attr("class", "bars");
zoomGroup.attr("class", "zoom");

barsGroup.attr("clip-path", "url(#bars-clip-path)");
xAxisGroup.attr("clip-path", "url(#bars-clip-path)");

d3.csv("data.csv").then((data) => {
  data.forEach((d) => {
    d.profit = Number(d.profit);
    d.revenue = Number(d.revenue);
    d.month = d.month;
  });

  var y0 = d3.max(data, (d) => d.profit);
  var y1 = d3.max(data, (d) => d.revenue);

  var maxdomain = y1;

  if (y0 > y1) var maxdomain = y0;

  x.domain(data.map((d) => d.month));
  y.domain([0, maxdomain]);

  xAxisGroup
    .call(xAxisCall)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", "10")
    .attr("x", "-5")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-40)");

  yAxisGroup.call(yAxisCall);

  const rects = zoomGroup.selectAll("rect").data(data);

  rects.exit().remove();

  rects
    .attr("y", (d) => y(d.profit))
    .attr("x", (d) => x(d.month))
    .attr("width", 0.5 * x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", (d) => HEIGHT - y(d.profit));

  rects
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "profit")
    .attr("y", (d) => y(d.profit))
    .attr("x", (d) => x(d.month))
    .attr("width", 0.5 * x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", (d) => HEIGHT - y(d.profit))
    .attr("fill", "grey");

  const rects_revenue = zoomGroup.selectAll("rect.revenue").data(data);

  rects_revenue.exit().remove();

  rects_revenue
    .attr("y", (d) => y(d.revenue))
    .attr("x", (d) => x(d.month))
    .attr("width", 0.5 * x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", (d) => HEIGHT - y(d.revenue));

  rects_revenue
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "revenue")
    .style("fill", "red")
    .attr("y", (d) => y(d.revenue))
    .attr("x", (d) => x(d.month) + 0.5 * x.bandwidth())
    .attr("width", 0.5 * x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", (d) => HEIGHT - y(d.revenue))
    .attr("fill", "grey");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `call` the `zoom` on the svg, all zoom behaviour is relative to the svg.

Imagine that your x-axis is at initial zoom level of length 100 representing the domain [0, 100]. So the x-scale has `range([0, 100])` and `domain([0, 100])`. Add a left margin of 10.

If you zoom by scale 2 at the midpoint of your axis at x=50 you would expect to get the following behaviour after the zoom:

- The midpoint does not move.
- The interval [25, 75] is visible.

However, since the zoom is called on the svg you have to account for the left margin of 10. The zoom does not occur at the midpoint but at x = 10 + 50 = 60. The transform is thus x -> x * k + t with k = 2 and t = -60. This results in

- x = 50 -> 2 * 50 - 60 = 40,
- x = 80 -> 2 * 80 - 60 = 100,
- x = 30 -> 2 * 30 - 60 = 0.

Visible after the zoom is the interval [30, 80] and the point x = 50 is shifted to the left.

This is what you observe in your chart.

In order to get the expected behaviour, you can do two things:

a. Follow the [bar chart example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-bar-chart) where the range of the x-scale does not start at 0 but at the left margin. The `g` which is translated by `margin.left` and `margin.top` is also omitted here. Instead, the ranges of the axes incorporate the margins directly.

b. Add a `rect` with `fill: none; pointer-events: all;` to the svg that is of the size of the chart without the margins. Then call the `zoom` on that rectangle, as done in this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4e3925cdc804db257a86fdef3a032a45).

Note that all the new examples on ObservableHQ follow the pattern "a" that needs fewer markup.

Comment: I got it to work, thank you very much, I had to make other changes such as adding `MARGIN.LEFT` to the clip-path cause the X-Axis was exiting it towards the left. But all in all it works. Can you have a look, If I went about it the right way? https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-zoom-not-centered-forked-1gj0eb?file=/script.js

Comment: I took a short glance at it and it seems to be alright.